# Amazon-lex returning clarification prompt for all inputs

Tags: amazon-lex

I am trying to create a chatbot in amazon lex but no matter what input I type it returns the clarification prompt to me. I have currently configured the bot with 2 slots `mnemonic` and `company` and with 2 sample utterances  in a single intent `requestParameterInfo`

`what is the {mnemonic}​ value for {company}​`

`what is the {mnemonic}​ value for {company}​ for the year {date}`

any suggestions why this might be happening ?

Comment: i'm having the opposite issue... no matter what I type in, Lex identifies some intent - never brings up a clarification prompt...

Comment: @RaduSimionescu make sure slots are required.

Comment: @AntonIva -in my case it was actually a LEX bug that got fixed in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to check:

- Make sure your `Slots` have a number of good example values.
- Make sure you have built the bot and are testing on the current version.
- Under monitoring, check the missed utterances and add them as sample utterances.
- Check your `Lambda initialization and validation hook` is not overriding or otherwise messing with the request.

If none of these are the case, it could be that the values you are providing for `{mnemonic}` may not be able to be identified by Lex. I've seen this issue when trying to detect `yes` and `no` as a slot, and wouldn't be surprised if other words, or non-words are not detected.

Comment: I just created a new bot and built it again with the same intents and data and it worked after that.