# Managing the flow of configured chat in AWS Lex console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I configured an intent with some utterances, slots, and fulfillment and I also attached validation code hook and fulfillment code hook. But I am facing with one scenario that if the intent is triggered the configured slots must be omitted and it should directly go to the fulfillment.
At last, I want to manage the slots by using conditional statements in code level.

Answer (score 0):

Untick required checkbox on the Lex console for the slots and you are good to go.
Good practice is to validate slots in `DialogCodeHook` but if you want you can do that in `FulfillmentCodeHook` as well.

If you directly want to go to Fulfillment then uncheck the `Initialization and validation code hook` under `Lambda initialization and validation` in the Lex console and give the function name in Fulfillment section.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436959/amazon-lex-not-prompting-for-missing-variables-when-using-codehook-validation), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453803/amazon-lex-returning-clarification-prompt-for-all-inputs/) for details.